# URI not getting encoded properly

Tags: java, encoding

I am hitting URI

`https://localhost:8029/rest/v1/organizations?filters=organizationId==189&organizationClass==1`

from postman(encoded uri), when decoded `&organizationClass==1` is replaced with `vganizationClass==1`

Comment: What is your actual code that shows the encoding and decoding?

Answer (score 0):

It seems yo me it is just incorrect URI.
As i understand == is not possible in correct URI. One of = should be percent encoded. And each = should be followed by & or end of URI.

But even if it is incorrect URI it should encode => decode correctly.
Reverse direction decode => encode may not work because initial expression looks not encoded at all. It is plain URI.